# Pandas Replace '0' with Variable Values using Dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe with zip codes and incomes. Some of the incomes are = 0, which is wrong.

I have a dictionary with each zip code mapped to the mean income for all incomes within that zip code.

I want to replace all of the incomes in my dataframe that = 0 with the mean income value for it's respective zip code.

I have tried this:

```
income = []
for row in df['income']:
    if row == 0:
        income.replace({0:{income_zip}}, inplace = True)
    else:
        income.append(row)
```

To no avail. I have found lots of resources to replace all 0's with the same value, I am just unsure how to replace a 0 with a variable value from a dict based on another value in the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to say this ?

```
income = []
for row in df['income']:
    if row == 0:
        df['income'].replace({0:{income_zip}}, inplace = True)
    else:
        income.append(row)
```

Comment: @bstrain Iterating over dataframe values is rarely the most efficient solution.

Comment: Yes, I know. I am only dealing with about 17k rows and am not going for speed. I am pretty new to python in general and am just wrapping my head around getting this stuff done. I will cross the optimization bridge when I come to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also define your transformation function and use `apply` on your dataframe along the axis 1 (rows):

```
def transform(row):
    d = {'zip_code_1': 'mean_income_1', 'zip_code_2': 'mean_income_2'}
    row['income'] = d[row['zip_code']] if row['income'] == 0 else row['income']
    return row

df = df.apply(transform, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this one-liner:

```
df['income'] = map(lambda x, y : y if y != 0 else income_zip[x], *[df['zip_codes'], df['income']])
```